# Deleting specific text from text file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a text files
`Text file`

```
>E8|E2|E9D
Football is a good game
Its good for health
you can play it every day
>E8|E2|E10D
Sequence unavailable
>E8|E2|EKB
Cricket
```

I wrote the following code for detecting sequence unavailable from the text file and write it in a new text file

```
lastline = None
with open('output.txt', 'w') as W:
    with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            if not lastline:
                lastline = line.rstrip('\n')
                continue
            if line.rstrip('\n') == 'Sequence unavailable':
                _, _, id = lastline.split('|')
                data= 'Sequence unavailable|' + id
                W.write(data)
                W.write('\n')
            lastline = None
```

It work fine , it detect the sequence unavailabe from the text file and write it in a new file , but i want it to delete it from the file which it read from like

input.txt

```
>E8|E2|E9D
Football is a good game
Its good for health
you can play it every day
>E8|E2|E10D
Sequence unavailable
>E8|E2|EKB
Cricket
```

input after code should be like this

```
>E8|E2|E9D
Football is a good game
Its good for health
you can play it every day
>E8|E2|EKB
Cricket
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I am not using `file.readlines` method, as it fetches all the lines from the file into a list. So, it is not memory efficient.

## Method 1: Using a temporary file.

```
import os
with open('input.txt') as f1, open('output.txt', 'w') as f2,\
                                                  open('temp_file','w') as f3:
    lines = []       # store lines between two `>` in this list
    for line in f1:
        if line.startswith('>'):
            if lines:
                f3.writelines(lines)
                lines = [line]
            else:
                lines.append(line)
        elif line.rstrip('\n') == 'Sequence unavailable':
            f2.writelines(lines + [line])
            lines = []
        else:
            lines.append(line)
    
    f3.writelines(lines)

os.remove('input.txt')
os.rename('temp_file', 'input.txt')
```

**Demo:**

```
$ cat input.txt
>E8|E2|E9D
Football is a good game
Its good for health
you can play it every day
>E8|E2|E10D
Sequence unavailable
>E8|E2|EKB
Cricket

$ python so.py

$ cat input.txt
>E8|E2|E9D
Football is a good game
Its good for health
you can play it every day
>E8|E2|EKB
Cricket
$ cat output.txt
>E8|E2|E10D
Sequence unavailable
```

For generating the temp file you can also use the [`tempfile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html) module.

## Method 2: [fileinput](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) module

No need of temp file with this method:

```
import fileinput
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f2:
    lines = []
    for line in fileinput.input('input.txt', inplace = True):
        if line.startswith('>'):
             if lines:
                 print "".join(lines),
                 lines = [line]
             else:
                 lines.append(line)
        elif line.rstrip('\n') == 'Sequence unavailable':
             f2.writelines(lines + [line])
             lines = []
        else:
             lines.append(line)

    with open('input.txt','a') as f:
        f.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: its not compulsory that its one line like just football , it may be 10 of lines , 100 of lines

Comment: @Angel And the other lines, I mean for example lines between `>E8|E2|E9D` and `>E8|E2|E10D` don't have `>`?

Comment: yes those line which are between `>` don't have `>` , actually `>` indicate the new line

Comment: @Angel I've added another answer.

Comment: @Angel I've one more answer, this one used `fileinput` module.

Answer (score 0):

You do it the right way.

All you need after you've done is to rename the file 'output.txt' to 'input.txt'.

(No, there's no easy way to cut a line directly from the file you open for writing.)

Comment: but output.txt only contain the data with sequence unavailable not the other data and the input.txt contain other data with sequence unavailable

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
os.system("cp output.txt input.txt")
```

This overwrites your input with your output file that has the removed lines.  `mv` can also used for renaming

```
os.system("mv output.txt input.txt")
```

This will only keep one file, where as `cp` will keep both

[You should probably use os.rename()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.rename)

Comment: its not giving the required output , kindly review it

Comment: `os` module has methods that can be used to rename or copy a file, I am not sure if `mv` or `cp` will work on windows.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary `cp` should, never tried `mv` on windows though

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary where did you disappear to? Haven't seen you in a while

Comment: @Stephan Studying for job these days.